# Storm Topology generating an exception

Tags: hadoop, apache-storm

I am trying t send my data to HBase from Kafka topic using storm spout acting as an Kafka consumer and sending the data to HBase I am facing the exception in the storm topology....

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: No leader found for partition 0 at 
storm.kafka.DynamicBrokersReader.getBrokerInfo(DynamicBrokersReader.java:81)
at storm.kafka.trident.ZkBrokerReader.<init>(ZkBrokerReader.java:42) at storm.kafka.KafkaUtils.makeBrokerReader(KafkaUtils.java:57) 
at storm.kafka.KafkaSpout.open(KafkaSpout.java:87) at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5629$fn__5644.invoke(executor.clj:542) 
at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__452.invoke(util.clj:463) 
at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No leader found for partition 0 
at storm.kafka.DynamicBrokersReader.getLeaderFor(DynamicBrokersReader.java:120) 
at storm.kafka.DynamicBrokersReader.getBrokerInfo(DynamicBrokersReader.java:68) ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is wrong with your kafka topic. The first line:

```
No leader found for partition 0
```

is the key here.

You're going to have to dig into kafka and fix that topic so that it has a broker that is acting as leader.